# How can I install an older version of Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, jekyll, osx-yosemite

I'd like to install Jekyll version 1.5.1 (on a Mac). Is it possible to do this? I found something about being able to downgrade, but I find it hard to believe there is no way just to install an older version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify the exact version in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'jekyll', '1.5.1'
```

Or install a specific version from the command line:

```
gem install jekyll -v 1.5.1
```

Comment: Cool. This is probably another issue all together but when I run that second command I get an error "ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension." Here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/7resg4F.png

Comment: Don't believe so. First time with a OSX! I'll install that now

Comment: You may also need to run `bundle update jekyll` if you use bundle and has it locked to an never version.

Answer (score 8):

You can mention the version you want to run.

```
jekyll _2.4_ serve --watch
```