# Selecting a specific jekyll version on Mac OS X

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm running jekyll locally on mac os x

```
 [19:55:14@emeraldjava.github.io]$ jekyll -v
 jekyll 2.5.3
```

but i've notice that the jekyll [version that github pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/) runs is

```
 2.4.0
```

How can i ensure i'm running against the same version locally?

Comment: Actually found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223567/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-jekyll

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be in sync with GitHub you can use the GitHub Pages Ruby Gem by following the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#installing-jekyll