# Jekyll, terminal displaying endfor as an invalid liquid tag

Tags: html, static, terminal, jekyll

I have a simple jekyll for loop but when jekyll compiles it it keeps saying that my endfor is invalid ?? what is going wrong?

```
{% for posts in site.posts %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">{{posts.title}}</a>
        <p>{{posts.meta}}</p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't think the error is caused by this block of code as I have tried it myself and even copied your code over. At first I thought it was because you used `posts` when there is a `site.posts` variable already, but after checking it worked fine. Maybe you didn't close another for loop before or after this? Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.

Comment: It happened after I updated jekyll to 2.5.3 is there a way to regress back to a previous version, at least till this is corrected?

Comment: are you using GitHub Pages? You can just change it in your Gemfile. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223567/how-can-i-install-an-older-version-of-jekyll