# Jekyll Serve command not working - Errors include MissingDependencyException and MissingSpecError

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, jekyll

As the title above says, I'm trying to build a site on localhost with `jekyll serve` but I keep getting several errors.

I've done all the steps described [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/01-setup/) to build my site, but nothing seems to work. I've tried several troubleshooting sources I found online, as well.

Also, the directory I'm trying to build with is a local GitHub repository.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I fixed it.

I ended up deleting my local repository and cloning it remotely from GitHub. That didn't solve it immediately, but the Gemfile on my local repository was from before I started having issues.

After that, I then kept getting an error where the version of Jekyll was incompatible with building GitHub pages. [This page had the answer I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598084/how-does-one-downgrade-jekyll-to-work-with-github-pages) - which was just changing the version number for `gem "jekyll"` in the `Gemfile` for the directory.

Finally, I ran a `bundle exec jekyll serve` and I got my localhost to run!